# Отношение к таблице через другую таблицу в Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

Есть три таблицы: "Users", "Subscriptions", "Packages". Таблица "Users" имеет связь One to One к таблице "Subscriptions" через поле Subscriptions.user_id. Таблица "Subscriptions" имеет связь One to One к таблице "Packages" через поле Subscriptions.package_id. Собственно вопрос: как оформить связь таблицы "Users" к таблице "Packages" с помощью функции отношения в Laravel Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак не оформляй. Оформи обе по документации к subscriptions, потом ты сможешь получать доступ по цепочке. В твоем случае ты сможешь получить доступ через Users->subscriptions->packages (это названия отношений я написал, у тебя будут как назовешь).
То есть ты оформляешь только непосредственные отношения. Но получив доступ к другой модели через отношение, ты получаешь доступ к ее полям, и ее ОТНОШЕНИЯМ тоже, а значит можешь хоть через 10 таблиц по цепочке отношений быстро получить доступ к чему угодно.